# Build custom property on <ng-template>

Tags: angular

I have a component which has two @Inputs:
  `@Input() identificador: string;`
  `@Input() descripcion: string;`

And I pass a property name as string for example("nombre")

```
<ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
    item.{{descripcion}} <br/>
    <small class="text-muted">item.{{identificador}}</small>
</ng-template>
```

I have this `ng-template` and I want to build a custom property for example inside of ng-template I want:

`item.nombre` this is an example, because I want this in base the values I send.

I've tried to do it like this: `item.{{descripcion}}` but it doesn't work

Any way how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess enclosing your property in square brackets should work:

```
{{ item[descripcion] }}
```

because that's how we can access dynamic property in javascript.